# Change filter on angular ng-repeat from chrome console

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, filter, console

Is it possible to change angular filter on ng-repeat loaded elements on chrome console?
I need to do this because I want to experiment some methods for overload part of an angular application from console once loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could filter off a global variable which you could change from the console. But I suspect you will also need to fire the digest loop